# "Spoilt child", but "he's spoiled"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, word-difference

According to [this](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spoil) dictionary, Americans use "spoiled" past tense and past participle, whereas British people use either "spoilt" or "spoiled."

So, my question is:

Can I say "a spoiled child" when I'm in the United States, instead of "a spoilt child"? Or maybe it's not possible because, in that particular example "a spoilt child" is a fixed term understood in American and British English.

"A **spoilt child** is rarely popular with other children.
Oh, that child. He's so **spoiled**."

### my afterthought:

I've just realized that I thought "a spoilt child" is a fixed term with a particular meaning and I have never thought that American people don't use "spoilt." I also thought that "spoilt" appeared as an adjective in both languages, which is not true.

Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiled_child) used that term!

Comment: @Max I've just edited my question.

Comment: @Max I've just realized that I thought "a spoilt child" is a fixed term with a particular meaning and I have never thought that American people don't use "spoilt." I also thought that "spoilt" appeared as an adjective in both languages, which is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S., we would say "a spoiled child." We just flat out don't use past participles like spoilt, learnt, or spelt, in any context. They're 100% BrE. I believe Canadians wouldn't use them, either. Although I admit, I have no idea whether they're used in Australia or New Zealand.

Comment: Exception: burnt, but usually only in fixed phrases such as "burnt orange"

Answer (score 0):

In Britain, a child can only be spoiled. Spoilt is something you do to homework, or cooking.